# How to decrypt JWE has alg ECDH-ES+A256KW use php

Tags: php, jwt, cryptography, jwk, jwe

I'm updating singpass v3 to v4 using php CI.
API getPersonal return jwe has alg ECDH-ES+A256KW. I copy it jwe to demo project (use js) of singpass it can decrypt. I have the same encryption private key with demo project

I tried lib simpleJwt it throw error "Key not found or invalid" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/328lw.png).
I'm trying lib web-token/jwt-framework but it throw Error: The algorithm "ECDH-ES+A256KW" is not supported.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm `ECDH-ES+A256KW` [is supported](https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/the-components/encrypted-tokens-jwe/encryption-algorithms) by the `web-token/` suite.
You have to install the associated package `web-token/jwt-encryption-algorithm-ecdh-es` and add an instance of `Jose\Component\Encryption\Algorithm\KeyEncryption\ECDHESA256KW` to the algorithm manager.

/!\ DISLAIMER : I am the author of the web-token/* suite and maintain the documentation.